# SAS Data Integration : SAP table extract error

Tags: sas, data-integration, sap-erp, sap-r3

This is the error code :

```
Line 115: ERROR: RFC_ERROR_SYSTEM_FAILURE Error in module RSQL of the database interface.    NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements. `
```

Error Log :

```
NOTE: Libref SAPENG was successfully assigned as follows: 
  Engine:        R3 
  Physical Name: PRORELOC
101        %rcSet(&syslibrc);
102        
103        %let etls_recnt = 0;
104        %macro etls_recordCheck;
105           %let etls_recCheckExist = %eval(%sysfunc(exist(SAPEng.CDPOS, DATA)) or
106                 %sysfunc(exist(SAPEng.CDPOS, VIEW)));
107        
108           %if (&etls_recCheckExist) %then
109           %do;
110              proc sql noprint;
111                 select count(*) into :etls_recnt from SAPEng.CDPOS;
112              quit;
113           %end;
114        %mend etls_recordCheck;
115        %etls_recordCheck;
MPRINT(ETLS_RECORDCHECK):   proc sql noprint;
MPRINT(ETLS_RECORDCHECK):   select count(*) into :etls_recnt from SAPEng.CDPOS;
ERROR: RFC_ERROR_SYSTEM_FAILURE
Error in module RSQL of the database interface.
```

Any idea why this happen ?
The table i tried to extract is called CDPOS. There is no error on other SAP table

Comment: Gensius, the SAS code appears to be okay, but you might have a connection issue trying to use INTO: to create the macro variable ETLS_RECNT. If so, then change your SQL code to create a table with a single column ETLS_RECNT and single row with the count, then use call symput within a data step to create the macro variable.

Answer (score 0):

RFC_ERROR_SYSTEM_FAILURE means that the RFC call went wrong, usually producing a short dump (transaction ST22) and/or system log entries (SM21). Check these logs to find out what exactly went wrong.